# How to process a lot of files in chunks in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of files (millions of small files),
I wish to process them in chunks (100K at a time), 
The files are located in diffrent path.
I thought of using woleTextFile but it get only directory name.
al textfiles = sc.wholeTextFiles("logs/data1","log2",..)
The reason I wish to process in batch is becuase it is million on small files
on S3. Running sc.wholeTextFile on the whole bucket it would take hours to complete.
Any Ideas?

Comment: why do you need to process in batches (chunks)? It will be easier to help if you explain why you want to do it this way.

Comment: I edited.Thanks for the coment Jake!

Comment: OK, not my area, but answer may be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947384/apache-spark-batch-processing-of-files.

Comment: also, google: spark batch process files. "Chunk" may not be the best search term

Comment: Thanks, but the files are zipped. I have looked this answer before.